# Displaying element to the left leaves a blank

Tags: css

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jGCx9/

I have `right: 28px` which causes the `span` element to shift left, but this does not leave space for the following elements (here, some text).

How can I prevent this blank from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` instead, and position it relative to the upper-left corner of its containing element. That way, it will be totally taken out of the normal render-flow, and it will not affect other elements. http://jsfiddle.net/jGCx9/1/

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 108px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, because `position: relative;` just allows you to move the specified element without any impact on other elements. Try a negative value for `margin-left` on your span, even if that is kind of a dirty trick it may work.

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -38px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```